# Abelian Group of order 108 that has 13 subgroups of order 3

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am trying to show that there are two Abelian groups of order $108=2^2 3^3$ that have exactly 13 subgroups of order 3.

I know the question is equivalent to show there are 26 elements of order 3 in each one of them .

The answer is :

$$G_1=\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$$

$$G_2=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$$

I know any element of order 3 in $G_1$ is of the form $(0,a,b,c)$ such that $lcm(|a|,|b|,|c|)=3$.( or 0f the form $(0,0,a,b,c)$ in $G_2$)

But how to show there are 26 different elements without using any computer software. I tried by calculating the choices of $a,b,c$  which is $2.3.3+3.2.3+3.3.2=54$.Of course there are similar elements. How to cancel similar elements in my calculating or what is the technique to solve the problem.

One of the way I thought about is :

calculating a=1,2,b=0,1,2, c=0,1,2 . So , we have 18 elements

next. take a=0, b=1,2 ,c=1,2,3. we have 6 more different elements, Then I took the last for a=0,b=1,2  and c=0. So add 2 different elements . The total will be 26 elements

I believe there is better method.

Thanks

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_3\oplus\Bbb{Z}_3\oplus\Bbb{Z}_3$ has $3^3=27$ elements. Only one of them is not of order three. Which one?

Comment: $(0,0,0)$. Wonderful. It easy in this way each one has 3 choices . so we have $3^3$ different elements . Nice. Thank you

Comment: Good job! ${}{}$